# Node.js: Path issues for EJS page templates

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Using a MEAN environment (Express 4) and EJS as a template engine, I am struggling with a path issue.

- Root path of my project: /Users/admin/projectX/
- path of pages (.ejs format): /Users/admin/projectX/views/pages
- path of partials(.ejs format): /Users/admin/projectX/views/partials

Code samples:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); //using ejs as template engine instead of jade
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); //defining absolute path of views folder

//sample route for calling index.ejs
app.route('/')
.get(function(req, res) {
   res.render('/pages/index'); //index.ejs is located in the pages folder (full path see list above)
});
```

For some reason I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "/pages/index" in views directory "/Users/admin/projectX/views"
```

IMHO the path should correctly add up to /Users/admin/projectX/views/pages/index, so why can't it be found?!

Comment: Have you tried omitting the beginning slash at the path: res.render('pages/index'); And do the files have .ejs extension?

Comment: How come the path remains valid with a missing slash in between?

Comment: By the way, that was the solution @dsdenes. I feel stupid as I was confident of having tried that before. Well, obviously not or I made a mistake along the way. Thanks anyways!